# Trie Tree. Unable to access memory

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, stack-overflow

I am a beginner at C++ and am have some issues with 2 separate errors. Unable to access memory and stack overflow.

This is my implementation for a Trie Tree, using pointers, of words containing characters a-z. When running tests, I can successfully add several hundred, or even thousands of nodes without issue, until it eventually crashes. Error: Unable to access memory. I more often get this error when I am trying to run a query and use the "isAWord" function. I also get a stack overflow when I try to run the deconstructor. Any help is appreciate, as I've spent 2 days trying to debug with little success.

```
#include "Trie.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;    

//sets up tree
Trie::Trie()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ALPH; i++)
        this->childs[i] = nullptr;

    endNode = false;
}

//add 'userInput' string to trie

void Trie::addAWord(std::string userInput)
{
    Trie* start = this;

    for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++)
    {
        int index = userInput[i] - 'a';

        if (start->childs[index] == nullptr)
            start->childs[index] = new Trie();

        start = start->childs[index];
    }

    start->endNode = true;
}

//returns true if 'wordFind' is in tree

bool Trie::isAWord(std::string wordFind)
{
    if (this == nullptr)
        return false;

    Trie* start = this;

    for (int i = 0; i < wordFind.length(); i++)
    {
        int index = wordFind[i] - 'a';
        start = start->childs[index];

        if (start == nullptr)
            return false;
    }

    return start->endNode;
}

//returns a vector containing the words in tree with prefix 'prefFind'

vector<std::string> Trie::allWordsStartingWithPrefix(std::string prefFind)
{
    string pres = PrefixRec(prefFind,*this);
    stringstream preStream(pres);
    istream_iterator<std::string> begin(preStream), end;
    vector<std::string> stringSet(begin, end);
    copy(stringSet.begin(), stringSet.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return stringSet;
}

//helper method for AllWordsStartingWithPrefix

std::string Trie::PrefixRec(std::string& key, Trie const temp)
{
    if (temp.endNode)
        return(key + " ");

    for (char index = 0; index < ALPH; ++index)
    {
        index = key[index] - 'a';

        Trie const* curChild = temp.childs[index];
        if (curChild)
        {
            key.push_back(index);
            PrefixRec(key, *curChild);
            key.pop_back();
        }
    }
}

//copy cons and assignment op

Trie& Trie::operator=(const Trie& other)
{
    Trie* newPtr = new Trie(other);
    other.~Trie();
    return *newPtr;
}

//deconstructor

Trie::~Trie()
{
    if (this == nullptr)
        return;

        for (int i = 0; i < ALPH; i++)
        {
            if (childs[i] != nullptr)
                childs[i]->~Trie();
        }
        delete this;
        return;
}


#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#define ALPH 26

class Trie
{
public:
    bool endNode;
    Trie* childs[ALPH];

    Trie();
    void addAWord(std::string key);
    bool isAWord(std::string key);
    std::vector<std::string> allWordsStartingWithPrefix(std::string key);
    Trie& operator=(const Trie& other);
    std::vector<std::string> wordsWithWildcardPrefix(std::string);
    std::string PrefixRec(std::string& key, Trie const temp);
    ~Trie();
};
```

Comment: Without seeing your header file, it seems you have ***two*** variables named `childs`. One global variable `::childs` and one `Trie::childs`. Those are two different and distinct variables.

Comment: And please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you put Trie.h header file in this question?

Comment: I added it to the bottom. Thanks. I will read the question check list, I thought I had been distinct but it looks i've got areas to improve on as far as asking questions. I also removed the extra bool and child variables, Some programmer dude was right that I had included, but it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also get a stack overflow when I try to run the deconstructor.

This is because of this line:

```
delete this;
```

This is what a [delete](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) does

> The delete expression invokes the destructor (if any) for the object
>   that's being destroyed,

You can imagine why calling `delete` from within the destructor would be problematic. (Hint: [Infinite recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Infinite_recursion))

You don't want any `delete this` in your code.

Once you get rid of this, there are other issues.(Although you may live just by fixing this). For instance calling the destructor explicitly as you are doing in this line(and several other lines)

```
other.~Trie();
```

From [iso cpp](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#dont-call-dtor-on-local):

> **Should I explicitly call a destructor on a local variable?**
>
> > *No!*
> >
> > The destructor will get called again at the close } of the block in which the local was created. This is a guarantee of the language; it happens automagically; there’s no way to stop it from happening. But you can get really bad results from calling a destructor on the same object a second time! **Bang! You’re dead!**

Replace the explicit destructor calls with `delete` and let it call the destructor correctly.

I would recommend replace any raw pointers and `new` and `delete` with [smart pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory). Start with [shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) to begin with. (raw_pointers are so 2010 ;))

Footnote: Get rid of these checks. They are non-idiomatic. It's ok and desirable for the caller to burn when calling a member function on a `nullptr`

```
if (this == nullptr)
    return false;
```

Comment: Thank you that helped me with the stack overflow.

Comment: @Ocmresh welcome to so. If you found my answer helpful please consider upvoting /accepting it.